# executing postgreSQL in Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm stuck trying to use `DB::select` to Execut a select query on a PostgreSQL database , in Postgres i can run this query no problem `SELECT "NumVersion" FROM "VERSION" WHERE "Type"='PH'` i actually had to be careful with the quotes and double quotes because if i take double quotes for example i get an error:

> Version does not exist

, now putting this exact code in laravel i do this

```
DB::select('SELECT "NumVersion" FROM "VERSION" WHERE "Type"=PH')
```

i get null in return because PH is not quoted and I don't know how to make it work, any help would be appreciate .
Thank you

Comment: try `DB::select('SELECT NumVersion FROM VERSION WHERE Type=$$PH$$') `

Comment: if i don't quote the tables i get error (i'm not at the office but i will try in the morning thank you so much )